# PHP second form on a page doesn't refresh target page if first one submitted

Tags: php, forms

I have a page that retrieves training ad list from the database and shows in a table. And another page that shows detailed information about training when clicked on training name. The detailed information page also allows to edit and delete the ad. When ad is edited or deleted page is redirected to the ad list. The problem is that if I edit an Ad and without visiting another page if I delete the ad when redirected to the ad list page the deleted Ad still is in the list. But if I delete the ad without editing it or after editing if I visit another page then return and delete the ad everything works properly. Sorry for a long question. Any kind of help is appreciated. 
Codes are as following.

Ad list page:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Couldn't connect database");
$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE trainer_id=$trainer_id ORDER BY id desc  ";
$result =   mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $totalPages=ceil($count/$result_per_page);
$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE trainer_id=$trainer_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $start, $result_per_page ";
$result =   mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
if($count!=0)
{
echo    "<table cols='4'  cellspacing='25'>";

echo    "<th>Training Name</th>";
echo    "<th>Trainer / Training Center</th>";
echo    "<th>Training Dates</th>";
echo    "<th>Registration Starts</th>";
echo    "<th>Viewed</th>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

extract($row );



echo    "<tr><td  ><a href='personal_ad_details.php?id=$id'>$training_name</a></td>";
echo    "<td >$trainer_name</td>";
echo    "<td >$training_start - $training_end</td>";
echo    "<td >$reg_start</td>";
echo    "<td >$view</td></tr>";

}

echo    "</table>";
```

Ad details page(edit and delete):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Couldn't connect database");
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){

 $currentID = $_GET['id'];
$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE id=$currentID";
$result =   mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
$row=   mysqli_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
echo    "<div id='ad_header'>";
echo    "<h2>
 $training_name</h2>";
echo    "<p>Trainer/Training Center:</p> $trainer_name ";
echo    "<p>Training Date(s):  </p>$training_start - $training_end";
echo    "<p>Registration starts:  </p>$reg_start";
echo "<p>Phone: </p>$mobile";
if($email!=''){echo "<p>Email: </p><a href='mailto:$email'>$email</a>";}
if($website!=''){echo "<p>Web Site: </p><a href='http://$website' target='_blank'>$website</a>";}

echo    "</br>";

echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div id='ad_main'>";

echo    "<p>Training details:</p> </br>"?> <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('personal_ad_details.php')?><?php echo "?id=".$currentID?>" method="post"> <textarea  style="position:relative; left:0%" rows="10" cols="25"  name="Telim_Melumatlari" ><?php echo $training_details; ?></textarea>
<?php 
echo    "</div>";

}
?>
<input style="margin:10px" type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE"></form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    include('misc.inc');


    $connect    =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                    or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $sql        =   "UPDATE ad SET training_details='$_POST[Telim_Melumatlari]' WHERE id=$currentID ";
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
    $url="personal_ad_list.php";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
          echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";'; 
          echo '</script>'; 
          echo '<noscript>'; 
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />'; 
          echo '</noscript>'; exit;

}

?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('personal_ad_details.php')?><?php echo "?id=".$currentID?>" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Ad?');" method="post"><input style="margin:10px; background-color:red" type="submit" name="delete"  value="DELETE AD"></form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

    include('misc.inc');


    $connect    =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                    or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $sql        =   "DELETE FROM ad WHERE id=$currentID ";
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
    $url="personal_ad_list.php";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
          echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";'; 
          echo '</script>'; 
          echo '<noscript>'; 
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />'; 
          echo '</noscript>'; exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: @DincaAdrian maybe you have an idea about the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your form action url:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('personal_ad_details.php')?><?php echo "?id=".$currentID?>" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Ad?');" method="post">
```

To

```
<form action="" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Ad?');" method="post">
```

**Note:** Also good practise is you should submit process code starting of the page:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Couldn't connect database");


if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

    include('misc.inc');


    $connect    =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                    or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $sql        =   "DELETE FROM ad WHERE id=$currentID ";
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
    $url="personal_ad_list.php";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
          echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";'; 
          echo '</script>'; 
          echo '<noscript>'; 
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />'; 
          echo '</noscript>'; exit;

}

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    include('misc.inc');


    $connect    =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                    or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $sql        =   "UPDATE ad SET training_details='$_POST[Telim_Melumatlari]' WHERE id=$currentID ";
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
    $url="personal_ad_list.php";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
          echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";'; 
          echo '</script>'; 
          echo '<noscript>'; 
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />'; 
          echo '</noscript>'; exit;

}


if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){

 $currentID = $_GET['id'];
$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE id=$currentID";
$result =   mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
$row=   mysqli_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
echo    "<div id='ad_header'>";
echo    "<h2>
 $training_name</h2>";
echo    "<p>Trainer/Training Center:</p> $trainer_name ";
echo    "<p>Training Date(s):  </p>$training_start - $training_end";
echo    "<p>Registration starts:  </p>$reg_start";
echo "<p>Phone: </p>$mobile";
if($email!=''){echo "<p>Email: </p><a href='mailto:$email'>$email</a>";}
if($website!=''){echo "<p>Web Site: </p><a href='http://$website' target='_blank'>$website</a>";}

echo    "</br>";

echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div id='ad_main'>";

echo    "<p>Training details:</p> </br>"?> <form action="" method="post"> <textarea  style="position:relative; left:0%" rows="10" cols="25"  name="Telim_Melumatlari" ><?php echo $training_details; ?></textarea>
<?php 
echo    "</div>";

}

?>
<input style="margin:10px" type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE"></form>

<form action="" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Ad?');" method="post"><input style="margin:10px; background-color:red" type="submit" name="delete"  value="DELETE AD"></form>
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts, but none of them worked for me. When I update information and immediately delete the ad the training list doesn't refresh

Comment: what you mean by refresh. you are redirecting that page. if <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" /> not working then use location for that and also check data base your query is working fine or not

Comment: yes it redirects to the ad list page. Query also works fine because after redirecting to the ad list page I visit another page and return to the ad list page the deleted ad doesn't appear on the list anymore

Comment: try : header('Location: personal_ad_list.php');

Comment: also add  header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); header("Pragma: no-cache"); on list page

Comment: Because of some output is sent header is not working. There were following code `<?php
include("misc.inc");
header("Cache-Control: no cache");
session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");
session_start();
if($_SESSION['auth']!="yes")
{
header("Location:user_login.php");
exit();
}
?> `   and I added header("Pragma: no-cache"); but no luck

Comment: beside that, manually refreshing page doesn't work either, I should go to another page then come back